# write multiple columns from multiple files in csv file

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a very naive question based on a problem I'm facing. I'm using the following loop to browse through multiple files (2 columns of data in each file) and write 2 columns from those files in a single csv file:

```
       path=raw_input("enter file path...")  
         for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
             listOfFile = glob.iglob(os.path.join(root, '*.txt')) 
             dataAll=[]
             for csvFileName in listOfFile:
                 csvList=[]
                 modifiedCsvList=[]
                 inp = open(csvFileName, 'r').read().strip().split('\n')
                 for line in map(str.split, inp):
                     csvList.append(line)
                     for item in csvList:
                         modifiedCsvList.append(item)
                         volume.append(float(item[0]))
                         intensity.append(int(item[1]))  #volumes comes as int as per the csv

                  volume=[]
                  intensity=[]
                  for vol, uv in zip(volume, intensity):
                      if vol >= float(volMin) and vol <= float(volMax):    #printing zones of peak based on user provided boundaries...
                      filteredDataStream = str(vol), str(uv)
                      dataAll.append(filteredDataStream)   #appending filtered data in dataAll list...
         outFile= path +'/'+'Out.csv'
         with open(outFile, 'wb') as outputFile:
             for items in dataAll:            
             wr = csv.writer(outputFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL) 
             wr.writerow(items)  #writing the maxOutList into CSV format in the same user provided path...
```

Input files:

```
file1:
0.89167 -11
0.90000 -13
0.90833 -14
0.91667 -17
0.92500 -17
....goes on
```

I'm working with 600 files with similar format data stream and format.

For single file if I use the above code then I'm getting csv like:

```
0.89167 -11
0.90000 -13
0.90833 -14
0.91667 -17
0.92500 -17
```

Now, I have multiple files and I'm wishing to get a csv with output looks like below (Each two columns comes from single file):

```
file 1.       file 2
0.89167 -11  0.89167    -11 
0.90000 -13  0.90000    -13
0.90833 -14  0.90833    -14
0.91667 -17  0.91667    -17
0.92500 -17  0.92500    -17
```

I’m not quite sure how to append in a csv files in an iterative way after each loop collects the data from corresponding files.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Your posted code fails on a variety of undefined symbols.

Comment: @Prune thanks for you comments. I can not paste the entire code as it is large. Probably undefined lists are giving the errors. The file structure is pretty simple 2 column format and its easy to read using my approach. I have also been able to write it in a csv file using above code (may have some indentation issue while copy pasting). However, I cant figure out how to get to the output format using csv writer.

Comment: you have to first create list with all values from all files - and later you have to write to file all at once. You can't add new column to file. It would need to read all data from file to memory, add new column in memory, and write all data again in file. It will be simpler to first create all columns in memory.

Comment: @furas thank you. I was thinking the similar thing. But do you have any idea, how can I extend a list by columns ? I mean, if I use `append` its gonna be adding along to the previous and so does in `extend`. I'm not sure I know a way to extend a list in column-wise manner. Some advice regarding this would be very helpful.

Comment: Posting all of your code is not an issue, as I specifically asked for the MRE instead.  If you follow the posting guidelines, we can give specific help.  Otherwise, you greatly restrict who can and will work with you, and your question may get voted closed.

Comment: @Prune thank you for the suggestion. I have edited the code. I hope its easier to understand now what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: better use `pandas.DataFrame` - it is simpler to read `csv` - `df = pd.read_csv(filename)` and it is simpler to add columns - `df["file 2"] = [ ... values ...]` or `df["file 2"] = other_df[column_name]`

Comment: @furas thank you. I'll give it a try and update. :)